# FullCalendar - Using 'Events as function' method for loading events, how can I get events to reload via javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, fullcalendar

I have my calendar pulling events nicely from my RESTful api using the methods described here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

So everything works fine when clicking the "next" and "previous" buttons to navigate between months. But how can I get events to reload for the current view using javascript?

For example, in my app the are actions that have side effects of creating Events in my back-end. And when those actions are performed, I would like the events to appear on the calendar via a calendar event re-load.

Currently, if I want my new event to show up, I have to go back and forth a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add an event using javascript I suggest you do

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                id: split[0],
                title: _EventName,
                start: _EventDateStart,
                end: _EventDateEnd,
                allDay: _AllDayEvent,
                description: _EventDescription
            });
```

This allows you to add events to the calendar without doing a full page reload. If you have the information at hand in your javascript you can change the values to fit it to your liking.

Comment: I was on the fence about this approach, but it makes a lot of sense and will save quite a few calls to the API. I implemented and it works quite well.